# jQuery Javascript how to keep click event from going null

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Here is a JSfiddle link to the script I am working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/bnjWQ/

To use it, you first click the button and then on the element you want to modify.

As you notice, when you click the button to apply it to the div, the property is disabled and you can't just click on other objects. I want to be able to click the button, and apply it to any object without having to reclick the button.

The original code I wrote was not as tidy as this code, but a very helpful person wrote this for me to fix a problem I was having... I can't seem to enable this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete or comment out the line setting currentInput to null in the div.editable click handler and the if statement in the css property input click handlers. http://jsfiddle.net/bnjWQ/2/

Comment: yes i tried that :/ but if you click the other buttons they are disabled after you click the first one

Comment: @Taylor - I updated to address not being able to choose a different button.